# How to check if dictionary key is null

Tags: ansible

I have json variable:

```
"variable": {
    "changed": false,
    "data": null,
    "failed": false,
    "index": "135"
}
```

How to test if `variable.data` is null? I tried these, none works:

```
when: variable.data is null
when: variable.data is None
when: variable.data is NoneType
when: variable.data == 'None'
when: variable.data == 'null'
when: variable.data == ''
```

getting either error

> The error was: template error while templating string: no test named xxx

or "when" conditional failing.

Comment: variable.data is not defined ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct test is [none](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#none) (all lowercase).

```
when: variable.data is none
```